# How to count_values and then groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to:

count_values to count the occurrences of the same value under **invoice_line_normal_price** and groupby **shop_name**

This here is my df:

[image: Here is my dataframe]

I'm trying to end up with:

[image: Desired Result]

So far i know I can use:

```
df.value_counts('invoice_line_normal_price').to_frame('counts')
```

to get the counts without the grouping, but how would I add the grouping here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So need `df.groupby(['shop_name'])['invoice_line_normal_price'].value_counts()` ?

Comment: For counts check secon danswer in changed dupe.

Comment: Thats good for me @jezrael. Just need to know how to have the shop_name showing on every line.. tried:

nr.groupby((['shop_name']),as_index=False)['invoice_line_normal_price'].value_counts()

but I get AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: I think problem is duplicated column `invoice_line_normal_price`, check it by `print(df['invoice_line_normal_price'])` if return 2 or more columns.

Comment: When I try this I get:

<code>Traceback (most recent call last):
Python/CouponRedemptions/start.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(v['invoice_line_normal_price'])
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'invoice_line_normal_price'</code>